# PHP Laravel reconstructing the json result to another json format

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.3

can soeone help to modify the json result to another result format.

I have this json

```
{
  "_links": {...},
  "total": 10,
  "data": [
    {
      "_links": { ... },
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "john@doe.com",
      "images": [
        {
          "imageid": 12,
          "name": "Trees",
          "url":"http://path/of/image.jpg"
        },
        {
          "imageid": 13,
          "name": "People",
          "url":"http://path/of/image.jpg"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then my goal is to achieve this kind of result:

```
{
  "_links": { ... },
  "total": 10,
  "data": [
    {
      "_links": { ... }
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "john@doe.com",
      "images": [
        {
          "12" : {
            "name":"Trees",
            "url":"http://path/of/image.jpg"
          },
          "13" : {
            "name":"People",
            "url":"http://path/of/image.jpg"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

SO basically on the second json I want the imageid to be a keyname inside the images object. I would like to collection in laravel instead of looping. something like:

```
collect($results)->each(function($value, $key){
   //code here...
});
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-mapwithkeys .You can probably use it on `data.images`

Comment: Why, the first structure makes sense and the second one does not

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah i know, but my client wants that results to be accomplish and its hard to explain that this is good and not that one. :)

Comment: Client management is the subject of a totally different web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to worked for now, but I'm not satisfied with my code because of the loop. if you guys have an idea to improve, please post your answer. Thanks.

Thanks to apokryfos for the idea in mapWithKeys().

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($result['data'] as $k => $v){
  $images = $v['images'];
  unset($v['images']);
  $keyed = collect($images)->mapWithKeys(function($item){
    $imageId = $item['imageid'];
    $data = [" $imageId" => [
      'name' => $item['name'],
      'url' =>  $item['url']
      ]];
    return $data;
  });

  $v = array_add($v, 'images', $keyed->toArray());
  array_push($newArray, $v);
}
```